# vtkProperty SetLineStipplePattern working but SetLineWidth not..?

Tags: vtk

I have created a `vtkLineSource` that is passed to vtkPolyDataMapper, passed to vtkActor.

```
actor->GetProperty()->SetLineStipplePattern(0xf0f0);
```

works like a charm. However

```
actor->GetProperty()->SetLineWidth(5.0);
```

does nothing.

Both methods are marked "This is only implemented for OpenGL."

Here's the snippet:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkLineSource> line1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLineSource>::New();
line1->SetPoint1(posvel1.x, posvel1.y, posvel1.z);
line1->SetPoint2(posvel2.x, posvel2.y, posvel2.z);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputConnection(line1->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
actor->SetMapper(mapper);
actor->GetProperty()->SetLineWidth(2.0); // TODO: Has no effect. 
actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1, 1, 1);
actor->GetProperty()->SetOpacity(0.5);
actor->GetProperty()->SetLineStipplePattern(0xf0f0);
actor->GetProperty()->SetLineStippleRepeatFactor(1);
// Further up, add actor to vtkAssembly
```

Line shows and has stipple pattern, but width is unaffected by whatever value I pass to SetLineWidth.

Edit: I already had a comment in my code. "Replace with vtkPoints polygon drawing instead of LineSource needed probably..." Tested this: Does not solve the issue, stipple pattern is there, line width does not work.

== Edit ==
What **alternatives** are there to draw a 2D dashed/dotted line in a 3D scene with vtk?

Comment: Those are 3 questions in 1. To higher your chances of having an answer in S.O., make one question at a time. See, for some people (ejem, me...) S.O. is a game and I will not go through the trouble of helping you if I can't get my 15 points back. ;)

Comment: For the OpenGL thing you can use the IsA function of the vtkRenderer in your scene

Comment: El Marce, fair point, I'll update the question. Not sure what you mean by "get my 15 points back" though... :/

Comment: For me it's the opposite, SetLineWidth works, SetLineStipplePattern has no effect. Which probably means that your code is correct, but something is wrong with VTK...

Comment: @Headcrab, did you find out what the cause was in your case?

Comment: The stippling is no longer supported (for the past decade), the issue has been reported several times, see e.g. https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues/15799. When you are using the new openGL backend (so VTK version at least 6.3) like me or Headcrab, the setWidth works, but the stippling does not. The fact that it works for you Diana means that you are using some very old setup - can you specify what VTK version and possibly what graphic card and openGL version you use (if you know)? I have no idea why the setLineWidth shouldn't work but knowing those things would be a start.